# how can i pass variable in a api url as api expecting?

Tags: php, api, curl

i want to pass $var[5] in to the {subscription_reference} in the url.$var[5] contains string value.

Here is my code

```
$url5 = $api_entry_point ."/subscription/{subscription_reference}/credentials";


    $ch5 = curl_init($url5);
    curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$user}:{$pass}");
    curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_GET, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch5, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output5 = curl_exec($ch5);
    curl_close($ch5);
    var_dump($output5);
```

Here are the various ways i followed and gone wrong.

```
$url5 = $api_entry_point ."/subscription/'.$var[5].'/credentials";

$url5 = $api_entry_point ."/subscription/![CDATA[".$var[5]."]]/credentials";

$url5 = $api_entry_point ."/subscription/$var[5]/credentials";
```

Comment: curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [param]);

Comment: $api_entry_point ."/subscription/".urlencode($var[5])."/credentials";

Comment: Does the api expect something like ..../subscription/123a/credentials ? What doest the documentation of the api say ?

Comment: @Vasil Shaddix yes its expecting something like that.

Comment: @aldrin27 this not about post.this about GET.also this is regarding api

Comment: @VasilShaddix yes its expecting something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a get request just put the parameters after the link with `?param1=param&param2=param2` etc etc.

If the request is post you will need to use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
```

Where `$params` is an array with your parameters.